# updating data in foreach

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to update data in table using foreach
 my code is

```
    foreach($_POST['marks'] as $key => $value) {

  mysql_query("update mark set marks='".$_POST['marks'][$key]."' where cid='1'");
}



<form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="marks[]"/><br />
        <input type="text" name="marks[]" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
    </form>
```

but its coming what iam entering value in last field is taking

```
   id      cid     marks 
    1       1       20
    2       1       20
```

i want o/p like this

```
  id   cid   marks
   1    1     20  
   2    1     40
```

please help me.Thanks in Advance

Comment: use only one time <input type="text" name="marks[]"/><br />

Comment: if you want to update table using cid than it will update all the record having cid=1 with the last fired update query use any unique value to avoid this confliction..

Answer (score 1):

Your table `cid value is "1"` for both row, so it updates both row, Use `"id"` column as condition,

```
  mysql_query("update mark set marks='".$_POST['marks'][$key]."' where id='1' and cid = '1'");
```

Comment: both row has same cid value so all time it updated both rows , so your are getting last entered value

Comment: Use both id and cid in where condition - Please check i have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update table using cid than it will update all the record having cid=1 with the last fired update query use any unique value to avoid this confliction.

```
      foreach($_POST['marks'] as $key => $value) 
     {
        mysql_query("update mark set marks='".$value."' 
where cid='1' and `uniqueid`='".$uniqueid."'");
     }
```

Comment: unique id can be anything which will be unique for every row

Comment: if you are updating it means some values will be coming from db where is that value that value may contain some unique id if you have taken any unique column in database